# Cannot find module '@babel/core'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I am following along with this webpack4/react tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyxI-6C2u4

I have followed it exactly up until the part where he runs npm start. The difference is, his app runs, and mine gets the error:

Cannot find module '@babel/core'

The full error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joeyf\Desktop\Code\Github\webpack4-sample\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/index.js main[2]
```

I have tried to reinstall babel-core but is still not being found. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack4-sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample setup of Webpack4 with React and Babel",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "Joey Fenny",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-rc.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules'),
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Here is a link to a git repo:

https://gitlab.com/jfny/webpack4-sample

Anyone know whats going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Try running this.

```
npm install @babel/core --save
```

babel changed their package so your `babel-core` will not be the same as `@babel/core`.

Comment: Just for people who happen to drop by here, due to a recent major version update from babel 6 to 7, the babel-loader splits up into versions 7 and 8 respectively.  If an accidental update to babel-loader 8 using "ncm -u" is causing this issue, just make sure you get babel-loader 7 by "npm install babel-loader@7".  Installation instructions clearly noted here: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Comment: i just ran this command yarn add @babel/core --save and it's now working while it was already install don't know why

Answer (score 53):

The recent Babel upgrade to version 7 changed the namings of the node packages.

For instance, now you have to install

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

to get it working with React. Then you can use these in your *.babelrc* file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Or as alternative, when not having a *.babelrc*, in your *package.json*:

```
...
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
},
"devDependencies": {
...
```

If you want to get more into it, you can checkout this recent [Webpack + Babel + React setup](https://github.com/rwieruch/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup).

Comment: Personnaly, I just had to add the package "babel-loader" and the error went away!

Answer (score 7):

I removed the existing
    `npm uninstall babel-core babel-preset-env babel-preset-react`

and added their new names
     `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react`
that's works for me as perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

for those of you who use @babel/core alongside babel-node:
i just installed @babel/core using `npm i @babel/core --save-dev` but when i tried to use babel-node it does not recognized the @babel/core package, i uninstalled @babel/core and installed it again using `npm i @babel/core --save` and it worked again!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to uninstall babel 6

```
npm uninstall --save-dev babel-cli  babel-core babel-polyfill babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2 babel-register
```

and then reinstall babel 7

```
npm i  --save-dev  @babel/cli  @babel/core @babel/node  @babel/polyfill  @babel/preset-env
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

my two cents, for people getting started with react, webpack, babel, jsx,
I got a problem with
`npm run build`

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'
```

When you tried to gradually install each component, you might run into a version conflict between packages, i.e., you might ended up with a `package.json` file like this

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "webpack": "^5.33.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
```

Clearly, the reported failed to load `babel-loader` is not because I did not have `babel-loader` installed.  Therefore, I think, I would try to re-install it again with `npm i babel-loader`.

And, I got this message

```
$ npm install babel-loader
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: indecision-app@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.33.2
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   webpack@"^5.33.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"2 || 3 || 4" from babel-loader@7.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!   babel-loader@"^7.1.5" from the root project
```

I noticed that I'm using Webpack v.5. Hence, I remove `babel-loader` from `package.json` file and do `npm i babel-loader` again.

This time, `npm run build` was successful!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to fix this issue using below command

```
npm install @babel/core --save
```

Answer (score 1):

babel-loader@8 requires Babel 7.x (the package '@babel/core'). If you'd like to use Babel 6.x ('babel-core'), you should install 'babel-loader@7'.

Answer (score 0):

try to install npm install @babel/core --save
if it does not work try to uninstall node_modules and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same error by removing all the babel modules from **dev Dependencies** executing the below command:

`npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env`

You can refer to this link if the above command does not work:

[https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8599#issuecomment-417866691]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with:

```
 npm install --save-dev babel-loader@7 babel-core babel-preset-env webpack webpack-cli -D
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this problem for a few hours and it mysteriously disappeared when I added a "devDependencies" section to my package.json file and moved the @types dependencies to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have react application and you get error change your babel config to below:

```
 {
"presets": [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "useBuiltIns": "entry",
            "corejs": 3,
            "modules": false
        }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-async-to-generator"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
    ["@babel/syntax-dynamic-import"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-classes", {
    "loose": true
    }],
    [
        "babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend",
        {
            "globals": ["Error"]
        }
    ]
]
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Go in by running on Windows, `%USERPROFILE%\.quokka`

The `~/.quokka` configuration is limited to the `config.json` file and any packages that exist in `~/quokka/node_modules`.

Put the following into `config.js`,

```
{
  "pro":true, 
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", " @babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", { "proposal": "minimal" }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
    ]
  }
}
```