# How to fix 'Cannot find module 'babel-types'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to setup react with babel and following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyxI-6C2u4. However I get that error when using npm start

I followed step by step the video. Then changed the babel-babel-plugins with @babel-babel-plugins except babel-loader, and changed .babelrc. Also add a new React component, but tried without including it and still gave me error.

**./package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

**./.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**./src/index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>   
</body>
```

**./src/Components/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HeroeClasses from './HeroeClasses';

const classList = ["Warrior", "Mage", "Hunter","Paladin","Druid","Shaman","Rogue","Warlock","Priest","DeathKnight"];

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <HeroeClasses classes={classList} heroeNumber="first"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**./src/Components/HeroeClasses.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HeroeMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`HeroMenu  ${heroeNumber}`}>
                <ul>
                    {classes.map(element => {
                        return (<li type="radio" class={`heroClass_${heroeNumber}`} name={`heroClass_${heroeNumber}`} id={`${element}_${heroeNumber}`}>
                            <label for={`${element}_${heroeNumber}`}>
                                {element}
                            </label>
                        </li>)
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

HeroeMenu.defaultProps = {
    classes: ['Warrior, Mage'],
    heroeNumber: first
};

export default HeroeClasses;
```

** Error Message **

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] D:\Users\josea\Documents\Jose\Proyectos\It_as_a_hobby\code\randomFights\src\index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-types' (While processing: "D:\\Users\\josea\\Documents\\Jose\\Proyectos\\It_as_a_hobby\\code\\randomFights\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js$20")
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\josea\Documents\Jose\Proyectos\It_as_a_hobby\code\randomFights\node_modules\regenerator-transform\lib\visit.js:17:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/index.js main[2]
```

Thanks in advance for your time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind starting again all over? I followed this same video earlier today and had no problem except where I had to change how babel is written. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067944/cannot-find-module-babel-core)
answer.

Edit:
And should you add react router to your application you might likely get a 404 when you reload a page, [This](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/) helped me

Comment: Gonna start from scratch, let's see if it works this time, thanks :D